# Include figure in Enumerate environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

This question is building off the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329409/have-enumerate-item-number-appear-at-top-of-tikzpicture)

I was attempting to place a figure within the enumerate environment and for the enumerate number to show up at the top, but I get the error `Not in outer par mode`

Can you help me fix this error so that my file can compile correctly and I get the Figure with caption to show up correctly?

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\raisebox{\heightof{1} - \height}{%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=9,
    xtick={0, ..., 7},
    ytick={0, ..., 9},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    area style,
  ]
    \addplot+[ybar interval] plot coordinates {
      (-0.50, 0) (0.5, 9) (1.5, 7) (2.5, 0) (3.5, 2) (4.5, 6) (5.5, 0)
    };
    \path
      \foreach[count=\i from 0] \v in {0, 9, 7, 0, 2, 6, 0} {
        (\i, \v) node[below] {\v}
      }
      (axis description cs:1, 0) node[above left, align=center] {grey\\level}
    ;
    \draw[ultra thick, blue]
      \foreach \x in {0, 3, 6, 7} {
        (\x -.5, 0) -- node[above=2pt, black] {0} (\x + .5, 0)
      }
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Histogram}
\end{figure}}

\item

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't the enumerate it is the raisebox that doesn't allow floats, it would make no sense to allow it as the only reason for the `figure` environment is to specify that the figure can move ("float") to a different position to help with page breaking, but a `\raisebox` needs some fixed content to raise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAybe you want this (I added an `\fbox` around the picture to visualise the control we have on the vertical placement of the picture):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, caption, float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{enumerate}
\item\leavevmode
\raisebox{\baselineskip}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[H]%
\centering\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=9,
    xtick={0, ..., 7},
    ytick={0, ..., 9},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    area style,
  ]
    \addplot+[ybar interval] plot coordinates {
      (-0.50, 0) (0.5, 9) (1.5, 7) (2.5, 0) (3.5, 2) (4.5, 6) (5.5, 0)
    };
    \path
      \foreach[count=\i from 0] \v in {0, 9, 7, 0, 2, 6, 0} {
        (\i, \v) node[below] {\v}
      }
      (axis description cs:1, 0) node[above left, align=center] {grey\\level}
    ;
    \draw[ultra thick, blue]
      \foreach \x in {0, 3, 6, 7} {
        (\x -.5, 0) -- node[above=2pt, black] {0} (\x + .5, 0)
      }
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\caption{Histogram}
\end{figure}%
\end{minipage}
}

\item

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to do it this way:

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{enumerate}
\item \mbox{}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    ... code of picture ...
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \captionof{caption}{Histogram}%
    \label{fig:histogram}
  \end{center}
\item
\end{enumerate}
...
As you can see in Fig.~\ref{fig:histogram}, \dots
```

The `figure` environement tells LaTeX that it is allowed to place the contents of the environment somewhere at the top or bottom of the page, or even on another page. 'Capturing' it in a box (`\raisebox`) contradicts this purpose and leads to an error.

[image]

Comment: You might want to suggest that the OP can use `\captionof{}` since wanting a caption is the most common reason people try to use floats when they don't want things to float.

Comment: @cfr Good idea, done.

Comment: @gernot, thank you for your response.  I cannot compile your code as I get the error, `! Package caption Error: No float type 'Histogram' defined.`  Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: @joe Sorry, somehow the `\captionof` command lost its first argument. Corrected now. Thanks for pointing it out!